# Gnuplot using column header

Tags: gnuplot

In gnuplot it is possible to use the column name (header) instead of the column numbers.

Let's assume the following datafile 'data.csv':

```
Time,X1,X2
3600,1,2
3601,3,4
3602,5,6
```

Now the following two ways are possible:

```
plot 'data.csv' using 1:2 title 'Param 1', \
     'data.csv' using 1:3 title 'Param 2'

plot 'data.csv' using "Time":"X1" title 'Param 1', \
     'data.csv' using "Time":"X2" title 'Param 2'
```

But if I want to perform some calculation before plotting - for example to plot the column 'Time' in hours instead of seconds, this is possible with the first way:

```
plot 'data.csv' using ($1/3600):2 title 'Param 1', \
     'data.csv' using ($1/3600):3 title 'Param 2'
```

But the following is not possible:

```
plot 'data.csv' using ("Time"/3600):2 title 'Param 1', \
     'data.csv' using ("Time"/3600):3 title 'Param 2'
```

How can I perform calculations on columns specified by column header?

Comment: Try `using ((column("Time"))/3600.):2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6401403/michael), use `column("Time")` in your `using` expression.

```
plot 'data.csv' using ((column("Time")/3600):2 title 'Param 1', \
      '' using ((column("Time")/3600):3 title 'Param 2'
```

Documentation for `column` and using can be found in under the `Commands -> Plot -> data` section of the [gnuplot documentation](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.4/Gnuplot_5_4.pdf).